# Does routerLink perform internal navigation without refreshing the page, and what happens when I use <a href in this context?

Tags: angular

I understand that `routerLink` performs internal navigation without refreshing the page.

However, if I use `<a href`, does it also perform internal navigation or does it refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a Single Page Application framework (SPA). Using href can break that design pattern.

**href** is is provided in `HTML`, it makes navigation possible, but not through angular components, but by reloading the entire page.

**routerLink** is provided by `angular`, and it makes it possible to navigate to a different component inside the application, without reloading the entire page.

While **routerLink** keeps the state of the page, **href** does not do so.